# How to fix this for loop for translating numbers

Tags: javascript

I´m trying to build a function to convert letters ("two thousand ninety-three") to numbers (2093).
So far it´s working but only with certain numbers. It works correctly until it hits numbers from 1000. From there it´s all mistakes:

```
parseInt("eight thousand two hundred thirty-three") // returns 8135
parseInt("seven thousand nine hundred ninety eight") // returns 7207
parseInt("three thousand eight hundred ninety nine") // returns 3207
```

```js
function parseInt(string) {
  
   
    var numberContainer = []

    const leyend = [
      ["one",1],["two",2],["three",3],["four",4],["five",5],["six",6],["seven",7],["eight",8],["nine",9],["ten",10],["twenty",20],["thirty",30],["forty",40],["fifty",50],["sixty",60],
      ["seventy",70],["eighty",80],["ninety",90],
      ["eleven",11],["twelve",12],["thirteen",13],["fourteen",14],["fifteen",15],["sixteen",16],["seventeen",17],["eighteen",18],["nineteen",19],["hundred",100],
      ["thousand",1000],["-",false],["and",false]
    ]

        var stringContainer = string.split(" ");
        console.log(stringContainer)
        
        for (let i=0;i<stringContainer.length;i++){
          for (let j=0;j<leyend.length;j++){
            if (stringContainer[i] === leyend[j][0]){
              numberContainer.push(leyend[j][1])
            }
            else if (stringContainer[i].includes("-")){
              var res = stringContainer[i].split("-");
              stringContainer[i] = res[0];
              stringContainer.push(res[1]);
            }
            else if (stringContainer[i].includes(" and ")){
              var res = stringContainer[i].split("and");
              stringContainer[i] = res[0];
              stringContainer.push(res[1]);
            }
          }
        }
        
        const definitiveNumber = numberContainer.reduce((a, b) => a < b ? a*b : a+b);
        
        return definitiveNumber
    
  }

console.log(parseInt("one")) // allgood: returns 1
console.log(parseInt("twenty"))  // allgood: returns 20
console.log(parseInt("two thousand forty-six"))  // allgood: returns 2046
console.log(parseInt("ninety seven")) // allgood: 97
console.log(parseInt("eight thousand five hundred fifty-seven")) // BAD: returns 8162
```

Comment: first of all, your code is not a function declaration, that's why you can't use `return` statement

Comment: What do you mean by "if the next has a bigger x10"? Can you provide better examples with the desired results?

Comment: there's no explanation for else conditions.

Comment: What if the next is slightly bigger? Like 40 and 41, do you multiply or sum?

Comment: Do you mean by "if the next has a bigger x10", that it's 100 or bigger? (.i.e has at least 3 digits? or it's division by 100 is 1 or more)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for shortening all your code in a row:

```
array.reduce((a, b) => a < b ? a*b : a+b);
```

Example:

```js
const array = [2, 1000, 40, 6]
const result = array.reduce((a, b) => a < b ? a*b : a+b);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Great answer! I thought he intended `a*10 < b ? a*b : a+b`, but the code doesn't match the textual explanation, so who knows

Comment: @salvatore that's right, if OP provides more examples and a better explanation, maybe we can provide a better answer. Otherwise, the MDN reference for *reduce* is great alone

Comment: I think this solution would fail with an array like this: `[2, 1000, 6, 40]` - it produces **2046**, while it should be producing **2240** (as far as I understood the question ;) ).

Comment: That´s amazing, although for the number 8233 it produces 8135. I´ll update the OP now with the full code at my apologies if i didn´t explain myself well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the amount of digits and compare the length you can convert the number to a string

Like this:

`(""+numberContainer[i+1]).length > (""+numberContainer[i]).length`

however this will only work with integer numbers

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm works a bit other than you think:

1. Takes the **first number**, compares it with the second, decides what to do (2, 1000 => 2000) - OK, **definitiveNumber = 2000**
2. Takes the **second number** from the array, compares it with third, decides what to do (1000, 40 => 1040) - not taken into account, **definitiveNumber = 3040**
3. Takes the **third number** from the array, compares it with fourth, decides what to do (40, 6 => 46) - OK, **definitiveNumber = 3086**
4. Algorithm stops, as there's no item after the fourth

**Your result is: 3086**

Do you want to compare the numbers, then step over them?

```js
const numberContainer = [2, 1000, 40, 6]
let definitiveNumber = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < numberContainer.length; i++) {
  if (numberContainer[i] < numberContainer[i + 1]) {
    definitiveNumber += numberContainer[i] * numberContainer[i + 1]
  }
  if (numberContainer[i] > numberContainer[i + 1]) {
    definitiveNumber += numberContainer[i] + numberContainer[i + 1]
  }
  // this is the solution
  i++
}

console.log(definitiveNumber) // expected output: 2046
```